# Angular fakeAsync test of promise resolution in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

For some reason, my `fakeAsync` tests will not resolve simple promises. I created a minimal example showing the issue (mostly `ng`-generated boilerplate).

My component under test contains a simple direct promise resolution in its `ngOnInit` method:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-test',
  templateUrl: './simple-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-test.component.scss']
})
export class SimpleTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  message: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    Promise.resolve('hello').then((content: string) => this.message = content);
  }

}
```

I am testing this promise with the following test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SimpleTestComponent } from './simple-test.component';

describe('SimpleTestComponent', () => {
  let component: SimpleTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SimpleTestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SimpleTestComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SimpleTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should display "hello"', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick();
    expect(component.message).toBe('hello');
  }));
});
```

But the test fails, meaning the promise is not resolved at the time of `expect`, despite the forced promise resolution via `tick()`.

It works when adding another explicit call to `component.ngOnInit()` at the beginning of the test. But this results in `ngOnInit()` being called twice. As far as I know, `fixture.detectChanges()` in `beforeEach()` should take care of `ngOnInit()` anyway.

What am I missing? Why isn't the promise resolved during `tick()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue. `ng g component` generates the test with `fixture.detectChanges()` in the `beforeEach(...)` function which is outside the `fakeAsync` zone, so the promise can't be resolved by `tick()`.

Moving `fixture.detectChanges()` into the `fakeAsync` zone fixes it for me:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SimpleTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should display "hello"', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.message).toBe('hello');
  }));
```

Comment: Spent so much time looking for this exact piece of advice!

Answer (score 3):

EDITED
You need to call component.ngOnInit() first, then tick(), then your expect method. Do this in each test method, that is what is working for my tests.

code snippet

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SimpleTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should display "hello"', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(component.message).toBe('hello');
  }));
```

Comment: This would call `ngOnInit()` twice because `fixture.detectChanges()` already calls `ngOnInit()` in the `beforeEach(...)` function. Moving `fixture.detectChanges()` to the actual test fixes it without calling `ngOnInit()` twice.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - `detectChanges()` muddies the solution.It should not be called unless you want to test the template - you should use a nested describe for testing templates where you may call `detectChanges()`